# Response with JSON on request-promise .catch() function

Tags: node.js, express, request, promise

I've found that all my [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise) `.catch()` methods are using the same logic in my application. So, I would like to write one maintainable function like so:

```
var handleError = function (error) {
  if (error.statusCode == 401) {
    res.json({
      'message': 'You\'re no longer logged in. Please check your settings and try again.'
    });
  } else {
    res.json({
      'message': 'Something when wrong and it wasn\'t your fault. Please try again.'
    });
  }
};

router.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
  request({
    uri: 'http://google.com/404'
  }).then(function () {
    console.log('It worked!');
  }).catch(handleError);
});
```

Although this doesn't work because the `handleError()` function doesn't have access ExpressJS's response object. How can I return JSON to the page and still maintain everything from one function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, it's best to write a middleware to handle it.

Alternatively, you can bind `res` object but again you will have to bind it everywhere to use.

You can learn more about [express middleware on its homepage](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

Also, see [`express-promise`](https://github.com/luin/express-promise) package